# how to solve this inequality,it's strange.

Tags: inequality

Prove that:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+2ac+2ad+2bd+2be+2ce\ge 3(ab+bc+cd+de+ea),$$
where $a,b,c,d,e$ are nonnegative real numbers.

Comment: What have you tried? If you show us where you are in your proof, we can either 1) correct a mistake you may have made or 2) help you finish your proof. But if we don't know what you are doing, it's difficult to intervene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter example: if $a=b=0$ and $c=d=e=1$, then

$$\begin{align*}
LHS &= 0^2+0^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+2(0+0+0+0+1) = 5\\
RHS &= 3(0+0+1+1+0) = 6\\
LHS &\not\ge RHS
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This is my mistake. I'm awfully sorry.